# Buildozer build failed on project install stage while it tries to install cython

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

This is the last portion of the buildozer log.Here I am trying to build a hello world app for the android.I have kivy 1.11 installed on my system.I have also installed latest version of cython but still it fails.I have tried building with both cython 0.28 and 0.29 but still the building fails while  installing Cython. I am new to Buildozer and kivy.PLease help.

```
[INFO]:    *** PYTHON PACKAGE / PROJECT INSTALL STAGE ***
    [INFO]:    The requirements (certifi) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
    [INFO]:    If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build
    [INFO]:    -> running python3 -m venv venv
    [INFO]:    Upgrade pip to latest version
    [INFO]:    -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activat...(and 23 more)
    [INFO]:    Install Cython in case one of the modules needs it to build         
    [INFO]:    -> running bash -c venv/bin/pip install Cython
    Exception in thread background thread for pid 20729:                           
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/home/vikas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/vikas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
        handle_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/home/vikas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
        return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/home/vikas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

  STDOUT:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Cython
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1231, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 688, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 208, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 598, in build_recipes
    ignore_setup_py=ignore_project_setup_py
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 778, in run_pymodules_install
    ), _env=copy.copy(base_env))
  File "/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/vikas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 925, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/vikas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 849, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/vikas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

  STDOUT:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Cython
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     CONDA_SHLVL = '2'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     CONDA_EXE = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/bin/conda'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/vikas/Desktop'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_CONDA_BACKUP = ''
#     USERNAME = 'vikas'
#     CONDA_PREFIX = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy'
#     XDG_VTNR = '2'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     _CE_M = ''
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     USER = 'vikas'
#     CONDA_PREFIX_1 = '/home/vikas/anaconda3'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/2b55102b_965c_46a4_9050_2c31334a22b6'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     PWD = '/home/vikas/Desktop/KivyHelloWorld'
#     HOME = '/home/vikas'
#     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/bin/python'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1585'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     _CE_CONDA = ''
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/share/glib-2.0/schemas'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER = '(kivy) '
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.156'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'vikas'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/vikas/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/bin:/home/vikas/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/vikas/.local/bin/'
#     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV = 'kivy'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1489,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1489'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     _ = '/home/vikas/anaconda3/envs/kivy/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/vikas/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/vikas/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/vikas/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

`apt install libssl-dev`

Then go into the directory where your buildozer.spec file is and run

`rm -rf .buildozer`

Then go ahead and try deploying again!

Comment: Thanks Eric it solved the problem.Tried to upvoted this but I have low reputation.Thanks for taking time.

Comment: It was a long way to rebuild bulldozer(rerun), but it was worth it!

Comment: Getting similar error on Mac - any idea how that can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

[install this virtual machine, it works](https://github.com/wzphood/kivybits/tree/master/KivyCompleteVM)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Well the VM didn't worked out.I tried to run buildozer android debug deploy run command but it says Aidl not found.

Comment: Did you do everything as written?1) `cd /home/kivy/Android/android-sdk-28/platform-tools/
sudo ./adb start-server
sudo ./adb start-server
./adb devices` 2) try it here `/home/kivy/Repos/kivy/examples/demo/touchtracer/`